# RPi Zero usb wifi fails, dhcpcd configuration not writable

Tags: wifi, pi-zero

I have an original Pi zero (not the W model) and I'm trying to use a wifi dongle.

When I run dmesg, I get this:

```
[ 1102.325699] usb 1-1.4.4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using dwc_otg
[ 1102.443985] usb 1-1.4.4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=5370
[ 1102.444029] usb 1-1.4.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1102.444050] usb 1-1.4.4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[ 1102.444070] usb 1-1.4.4: Manufacturer: Ralink
[ 1102.444086] usb 1-1.4.4: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 1102.545693] usb 1-1.4.4: reset high-speed USB device number 13 using dwc_otg
[ 1102.657215] ieee80211 phy4: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
[ 1102.713803] ieee80211 phy4: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
[ 1102.720652] ieee80211 phy4: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[ 1104.822934] ieee80211 phy4: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[ 1104.823160] ieee80211 phy4: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
[ 1105.207608] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

The output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b95:772b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But when I try to set up the networking, I get an error box that says:

```
Error saving /etc/dhcpcd.conf The dhcpcd configuration file is not writeable.
```

I've looked at the file and it should be writeable.
The output for ls -l is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Desktop  
drwxr-xr-x 5 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 04:52 Documents  
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Downloads  
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Music  
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Pictures  
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Public  
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 04:52 python_games  
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Templates  
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Videos
```

I would appreciate any help you could give me on this.

Comment: Inser the wifi dongle and rus 'lsusb' and show us the output of 'ls -l' for the dhcpcd.conf.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b95:772b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 5 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 04:52 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 04:52 python_games
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 10 05:10 Videos

Comment: Bill, when you are giving output from commands, you really need to format it readably or people will just skip the question. I reformatted the `dmesg` output in your question as originally asked, and I just edited the question to add the `lsusb` output in a readable form (you may not see this until a couple of moderators above the edit). In general, when you have further information from comments, always update the question or answer to include it.

Comment: I've edited this to remove the ambiguous claim that the wifi dongle "isn't recognized" -- clearly it is recognized, so what you meant by this is anyone's guess (please edit it in if appropriate).  The only actual problem you describe *explicitly* is the problem with the dhcpd config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct this problem by reloading Raspbian, from the same NOOBS. After reloading Raspbian, the USB wifi dongle was detected and I was able to use the drop down to search for the wifi host and enter my password.